# would rather have+v3 in negative

Tags: grammar

''I would rather have shown him my love''

How can I make this sentence negative?

A)I would ***not*** rather have shown him my love.

B)I would rather ***haven't*** shown him my love.

Answer (score 1):

There are two negations:

- I would **rather not** have shown him my love -- this negates the preference
- I would rather have **not shown** him my love -- this negates the showing

In practice they mean pretty much the same thing.